# Loading CSS and JS scripts of WordPress plugin only on a few pages?

Tags: wordpress

I used these two plugins named "Everest-tab-lite" and "easy-testimonials" on only one of my pages with id="15280", but their CSS and JS scripts load on all of the pages. For restricting the scripts I tried two ways but, did not work. I don't know what I did wrong. Is there any way to solve this issue?

The first way, I added bellow code at the end of functions.php file.

```
function conditionally_load_plugin_js_css(){
if(! is_page( array(15280) ) ){ # Load CSS and JS only on Pages with ID 4 and 12    
wp_dequeue_script('easy-testimonials'); # Restrict scripts.
wp_dequeue_style('easy-testimonials'); # Restrict css.  
wp_dequeue_script('everest-tab-lite'); # Restrict scripts.
wp_dequeue_style('everest-tab-lite'); # Restrict css.
}
}   
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'conditionally_load_plugin_js_css' );
```

The second way, I added the bellow code at the end of functions.php file.

```
function remove_wpetl_extras() {
remove_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wpetl_enqueue_scripts');
remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'wpetl_enqueue_styles');
}

if( ! is_page('15280') ) {
add_action('wp_head', 'remove_wpetl_extras');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just need to check for **order priority**

> priority
>   (int) (Optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action. Default value: 10 [Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#parameters)

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'conditionally_load_plugin_js_css', 100);
```

Change the priority to `100` or higher `999` because most plugins uses high values like `99` or even more and you need to override that.

Also please note that if you want to completely remove a style or script, you need to `dequeue` your scripts then `deregister` it.

---

**Edit:**

I see the problem. I've tested the code and it works but you must write the **Exact Name** of the style/script.

In your case, Both plugins adds some stylesheets and scripts, `Easy Testimonials` adds 6 stylesheets and 2 scripts:

```
easy_testimonial_style
single-testimonial-block
random-testimonial-block
testimonials-list-block
testimonials-cycle-block
testimonials-grid-block

easy-testimonials-reveal
gp_cycle2 (jquery.cycle2)
```

And `Everest Tab Lite` adds 3 more stylesheets and 1 script:

```
et-frontend-style
et_fontawesome_style
et-animate-style

et-frontend-script
```

> Please note that WordPress will automatically add `-css` at the end of
>   the stylesheet name. i.e `et-frontend-style` will show as
>   `et-frontend-style-css`

So your function would be:

```php
function conditionally_load_plugin_js_css() { 

    // Load CSS and JS only on Pages with 15280 
    if(! is_page( array(15280) ) ) {

        // Easy testimonial
        wp_dequeue_style('easy_testimonial_style'); 
        wp_dequeue_style('single-testimonial-block'); 
        wp_dequeue_style('random-testimonial-block'); 
        wp_dequeue_style('testimonials-list-block'); 
        wp_dequeue_style('testimonials-cycle-block'); 
        wp_dequeue_style('testimonials-grid-block');
        // scripts
        wp_deregister_script('gp_cycle2');
        wp_deregister_script('easy-testimonials-reveal');

        // Everest Tab Lite
        wp_dequeue_style('et-frontend-style');
        // Keep these if you like fontawesome and animate.css
        wp_dequeue_style('et_fontawesome_style');
        wp_dequeue_style('et-animate-style');
        // script
        wp_deregister_script('et-frontend-script');
    } 
} 
// Everest Tab Lite has priority more than 9999 so i changed the priority to 99999
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'conditionally_load_plugin_js_css', 99999);
```

Comment: I changed the priority to 100, 999 and higher number. but when I check the network section of my browser all the scripts of mentioned plugins exist till now and not removed.
Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: @Zoha Maybe that because of cache, Try to check the small checkbox called `Disable cache` when you test.. see [photo](https://i.ibb.co/qJxv7rR/fsdf.png)

Comment: Thank you for your helping.
I disabled the cache, clear browser data and put bellow code in function.php file. But still doesn't work.

//here is the code >> 
function conditionally_load_plugin_js_css(){
if(! is_page( array(15280) ) ){ # Load CSS and JS only on Pages with 15280
wp_dequeue_script('easy-testimonials'); 
wp_dequeue_style('easy-testimonials');
wp_dequeue_script('everest-tab-lite'); 
wp_dequeue_style('everest-tab-lite');
}
}   
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'conditionally_load_plugin_js_css', 9999);

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! I restricted all CSS and js files except "jquery.cycle2.min.js".  Does it because of dots? Could you please, help me to control this file, too.

Comment: @Zoha Yes, It loaded by Easy Testimonials too but in different name `gp_cycle2`. Actually my bad, i missed those scripts. I updated the answer again.